# Securely share files with medical patients (HIPAA compliant)?

Tags: cloud-storage, sharing

Looking for a service or platform where we would have HIPAA-compliant cloud based storage which medical patients would go to retrieve test results, etc. in the form of pdf or other document.  There would need to be some sort of authentication scheme to **make sure that the file is only accessible by the individual patient**.  Would also need to have some way for us to **programmatically communicate instructions to the patient to retrieve the report** and a way for us to **programmatically push files from an (LIS) server (Windows, I believe)** to this cloud based storage.

We would normally use something like MyChart, but **not all of these "patients" are actually in our standard EMR system** (eg. for many, we **only have their info based on the test submission and result forms** we get from them).

Anyone know which platforms, services would be the best for this kind of thing?